# Check if a word is spelled correctly

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a typing tutor, and i dont know what to do anymore. 
I have a database which contains the text for my typing tutor. This text is shown in a JTextfield. Under this TextField there is a another TextField which belongs to the user. The user must type over the text shown in the JTextField.

Now my problem is i dont know how to check if the user correctly spelled the word and i dont know what i need to search for

Comment: So you don't know. Is there any question about a specific problem in your code, or are you just looking for sympathy?

Comment: What do you mean you do not know , can't you just retrieve the string from the db and compare it with the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String st1=textField1.getText();
String st2=textField.getText();
if (st1.equals(st2)){
  System.out.println("The given string is equals");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some sample code?
If you have an array of correctly spelled words, `words` and the word the user spelled, `userword` then you could have something like this:

```
for(String word:words){
   if(word.equals(userword)){
      //  word was correctly spelled
    } else if(word.startsWith(userword.substring(0,2))){
       // word was incorrectly spelled
       // tweak substring to see how many letters wrong
    } else {
       // word unknown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hunspell4Eclipse is an Eclipse plug-in, that integrates the Hunspell spelling tool as an Eclipse’s Spell Checking Service.

This plug-in is capable to spell checking with any Hunspell dictionary.

http://code.google.com/p/hunspell4eclipse/

Comment: Irrelevant, OP is making a typing tutor which checks that you have typed everything **exactly** as shown.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to compare the word, or text that the user will be seeing, compared to what they have typed in.

The proper way to compare strings is with the .equals() method, you probably don't want to use the .equalsIgnoreCase(), as that ignores capital letters.

Like what others have mentioned above, there are several ways of comparing them. I particularly like zovegames' example, it breaks the user input into a substring to see how many letters the user was off, and can help you to get an accuracy counter, or accuracy percentage algorithm easier.